# Sending form data via email and show message without refresh or change page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this form, it works perfectly but when submitted/failed it swaps to another page where the message is showed.

HTML

```
<form action="envio.php" method="post">
    <label>Nombre </label>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <label>Email</label> 
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <label>Teléfono</label> 
    <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
    <label>Mensaje</label>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

**envio.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@gmail.com"; // email destinatario
    $from = $_POST['email']; // email del cliente
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mes = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "Formulario web";
    $subject2 = "Copia de su formulario de consulta";
    $message = $name . " con número de teléfono: " . $phone . " escribió lo siguiente:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Aquí tiene una copia de su mensaje " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    $success = (preg_match("/^[0-9]{9}$/",$phone) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$name) && $mes!='' && filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));

    if ($success){
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // copia para el cliente
        echo "Formulario enviado. Muchas gracias " . $name . ", en breve contactaremos con usted.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Lo sentimos, se ha producido un error al enviar el formulario, revise su contenido y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }}
```

I just want to show the messages in the `if/else` under the 'send' button after click it, without refresh, I think it can be done with JQuery/Vanilla but I have no clue. How can JS know if the form was submitted successfully? How can I tell JS where to insert the message?

Comment: Maybe a copying error, but you have a syntax error on your `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`. You have no close `}`

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, it was a copying error, thanks.

Comment: Use jQuery AJAX as you mentioned. Page 1 has the form and the jQuery. Page 2 has the execution of the script that. In your jQuery you can specify a placeholder to return the success or failure of your script on Page 2 (like a div or span or something)

Comment: @Rasclatt, so I should remove both echos from the .php and show the message using JQuery, maybe in an empty div? How can JQuery knows if the form was submitted successfuly? When I click the submit button it shows an empty page with only the success/failure message, how can I avoid this? Thanks and sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Sorry I made a couple little changes right now. There were some tiny (but important) text errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comments and because it's hard to explain in such a little space:

**page1.php**

```
    <!-- Name the form myform as an id -->
    <form action="page2.php" method="post" id="myform">
        <label>Nombre </label>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <label>Email</label> 
        <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <label>Teléfono</label> 
        <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
        <label>Mensaje</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea><br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <!-- Invisible response container -->
    <div id="response"></div>
<script>
    $("#myform").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
                 // PHP page  
                 url : 'page2.php',
                 // Takes all data from form
                 data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                 // Puts response into the container
                 success: function(response) {
                    $("#response").html(response);
                 }
        });    
        // This stops the page from reloading on submit
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

**page2.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@gmail.com"; // email destinatario
    $from = $_POST['email']; // email del cliente
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mes = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "Formulario web";
    $subject2 = "Copia de su formulario de consulta";
    $message = $name . " con número de teléfono: " . $phone . " escribió lo siguiente:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Aquí tiene una copia de su mensaje " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    $success = (preg_match("/^[0-9]{9}$/",$phone) && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$name) && $mes!='' && filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));

    if ($success){
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // copia para el cliente
        echo "Formulario enviado. Muchas gracias " . $name . ", en breve contactaremos con usted.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Lo sentimos, se ha producido un error al enviar el formulario, revise su contenido y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }
}
```